# Using TweenLite inside a class to tween a member variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

I have the following code (stripped down):

```
public class Character extends MovieClip
{
  var happiness:uint;

  public Character()
  {
    happiness = 0;
  }

  private function doTheTween():void
  {
    TweenLite.to(this, 3, { happiness:100, onComplete:onTweenComplete } );
  }

  private function onTweenComplete():void
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

When tracing the `happiness` variable every frame it stays at 0 after the tween has been called, and the `onTweenComplete` function is never called.  Is it even possible to use TweenLite in this manner or have I missed something stupidly obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you didn't, it is possible. Just try to make happiness variable of Number type, and make that variable public.

Comment: Making the variable `public` did the trick, strange because I thought variables were declared as public by default when you use `var` on its own.. Many thanks =) (will accept as correct in 10 mins)

Comment: By default the variable is being declared as internal, this means that variable is accessible from other classes within the same package. But in your case TweenLite isn't in that package.